# How to integrate an external NLP technique to Dialogflow?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I would like to use Dialogflow interface to create a voice assisted chatbot. 
Still, I would like to be able to add my own components to it. 
How can this be done ? If I have a python script with an NLP technique I'd want to add to my chatbot.
Dialogflow is mainly about NER and let's say I want to add TFIDF and text simplification to what's retrieved in my document.
I looked at the documentation and couldn't find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a Webhook: each intent is 'forwarded' to your webhook (ie custom app or script) and you have full access to the text provided by the user as well as the DialogFlow contexts/entities.
In your webhook you can can do what you want, including modifying the response to the user.

Hope it helps.

Beppe

Comment: Thank you ! How to pass the full user input/ query and not just the entities/parameters to the webhook (python) ?

Comment: Normally the webhook receives the whole payload (user input, entities, contexts, etc..), see https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json. Depending on your API (python, java, node) you should be able to get what you need navigating the objects which wrap the JSON sent via a REST call.